# Why was this review item in the 'First answers' queue invalidated?

Tags: support, review, new-users

I'm wondering why [the 'First answers' review item](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/68927) for an [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/65906) by [Cordel Michael](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63231/cordel-michael) to '[Can Kakashi use the jutsu he copied without the Sharingan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13811)' is invalidated, as shown in the [timeline for the post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/65906/timeline).

The timeline shows that the answer was not modified (no edits/deletion/undeletion) after posting. It is possible that some modification might have happened during the [5 minute edit grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info), but I believe even if it were so it couldn't have invalidated the review item based on the rules for invalidation as well as the timeline of events on this post.

- The 'First answers' review item was created at 2021-11-13 03:50:56Z, simultaneously with the creation of the post. It was invalidated around **36 minutes** later at 2021-11-13 04:26:45Z.
- The corresponding 'Late answers' review item was created at 2021-11-13 04:10:20Z, which is around **20 minutes** after the post was created<sup>1</sup>. This review item  was not invalidated, since [I was able to complete the review](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/68928) around **2 hours 50 minutes** later at 2021-11-13 06:40:40Z.
- I have looked at the following posts on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but none of the reasons given there seem to be applicable here:

  - From '[When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581)':

    > If the review task is removed due to other circumstances outside the queue (e.g. a moderator deletes a post that is being reviewed, outside the queue), it is marked "invalidated" or "no longer reviewable".
  - From '[When does a first post review get invalidated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369431/when-does-a-first-post-review-get-invalidated?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1232694_369431)':

    > Posts more than 14 days old were not eligible for the first posts queue.
  - From '[Do posts in the first answers and first questions queues age out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369765)':

    > Review tasks in both *First questions* and *First answers* are invalidated in any of the following cases:
    >
    > - 14 days elapse since the `CreationDate` of the post
    > - The score of the post is >= 3
    > - For answers, if the post owner rep goes over 250
    > - Post deleted
    > - Question closed
  - From '[First posts escape review when user deletes and undeletes post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361253)':

    > [I]t seems to be possible to avoid your first post from being reviewed simply by deleting it, waiting a few minutes (until the review item becomes invalidated) and undeleting it.

So, why was this 'First answers' review item invalidated?

---

<sup>1: This makes sense since an eligible post cannot enter the 'Late answers' queue before 15 minutes from the time of its creation, and the process that sends it to the queue runs approximately once every 5 minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220420/review-update-pattern/220431#220431)).</sup>

Comment: Perhaps related, on Meta SE: [Why were the First Answers and Low Quality Posts reviews for this answer invalidated for no apparent reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382255)